# Json file works but not when getting url

Tags: c#, json

I have tried to get my json table from a url. I have tried alot of diffrent codes but end up with the same error.

- NameResolutionFailure

I have no idea how to solve it.

Here is one example of how I have written the code

```
var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://api.trafiklab.se/samtrafiken/resrobotstops/GetDepartures.json?key=KEY&apiVersion=2.2&locationId=7420752&coordSys=RT90");
```

Stacktrace

```
System.Net.WebException was caught
HResult=-2146233079
Message=Det gick inte att matcha fjärrnamnet: 'api.trafiklab.se'
Source=System
StackTrace:
   vid System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   vid System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   vid System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
   vid ConsoleApplication2.Program._download_serialized_json_data[T](String url) i
```

Comment: Could you add a stack trace of the error?

Comment: `NameResolutionFailure` denotes a networking problem. The IP address of `api.trafiklab.se` cannot be resolved by the DNS server. Make sure you got the correct and up-to-date Url.

Comment: I dont get a stack trace in my window. Or atleast cant find it. :-) The link is correct. It works fine in my browser. Could it be I am behind a proxy that denies it?

Comment: What do you get when try getting this json via browser? You probably should update the url.

Comment: I get a json list in the output window in the browser.

Comment: From Statck Trace i got `Unable to match the remote name : ' api.trafiklab.se '`., Thanks to Translate.Google.com ;-)

Comment: This is what I get from your link with: "{
 "reason":"Access denied for the Developer Key":"KEY"
  }". Is this what you need to get?

Comment: I have other error with your code: "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
But from the browser I get something (or what it seems to be the file)

Comment: Ok, obviously the uri you pass requires authentication. But the code works. I don't get the same error than you

Comment: I have removed the key in the code above. So if you run the code above it will fail. You need to have a api key of course. But if I have my key in I will get the above error.